# How to rearrange the default dashlet of alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Whenever a new user is created using alfresco he  will be presented with default four dashlets. Namely:

1. My Sites
2. My activities
3. My Tasks
4. My Documents.

Since I dont want `My task`, me with little help from html tutorial, modified My task to look like this

[image]

Is there any way to change the default layout. So the My Task will be on top and My Sites will be below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a default installation, the quickest solution is to copy `webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-data/presets/presets.xml` to `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/presets/presets.xml` look up the user-dashboard preset and edit (the copy) so it reads:

```
<!-- Well known preset used to generate the default User dashboard -->
<preset id="user-dashboard">
   <components>
      <!-- title -->
      <component>
         <scope>page</scope>
         <region-id>title</region-id>
         <source-id>user/${userid}/dashboard</source-id>
         <url>/components/title/user-dashboard-title</url>
      </component>
      <!-- dashboard components -->
      <component>
         <scope>page</scope>
         <region-id>full-width-dashlet</region-id>
         <source-id>user/${userid}/dashboard</source-id>
         <url>/components/dashlets/dynamic-welcome</url>
         <properties>
            <dashboardType>user</dashboardType>
         </properties>
      </component>
      <component>
         <scope>page</scope>
         <region-id>component-1-1</region-id>
         <source-id>user/${userid}/dashboard</source-id>
         <url>/components/dashlets/my-tasks</url>
      </component>
      <component>
         <scope>page</scope>
         <region-id>component-1-2</region-id>
         <source-id>user/${userid}/dashboard</source-id>
         <url>/components/dashlets/my-sites</url>
      </component>
      <component>
          <scope>page</scope>
          <region-id>component-2-1</region-id>
          <source-id>user/${userid}/dashboard</source-id>
          <url>/components/dashlets/my-activities</url>
      </component>
      <component>
          <scope>page</scope>
          <region-id>component-2-2</region-id>
          <source-id>user/${userid}/dashboard</source-id>
          <url>/components/dashlets/my-documents</url>
          <properties>
             <height>240</height>
          </properties>
      </component>
   </components>
   <pages>
      <page id="user/${userid}/dashboard">
         <title>User Dashboard</title>
         <title-id>page.userDashboard.title</title-id>
         <description>Users dashboard page</description>
         <description-id>page.userDashboard.description</description-id>
         <template-instance>dashboard-2-columns-wide-right</template-instance>
         <authentication>user</authentication>
      </page>
   </pages>
</preset>
```

Be clear that this will affect only users visiting share the first time after you made the change.

Comment: how to do it for old users?

Comment: Update cm:content of Repository/Sites/surf-config/user/a_username/dashboard.xml for each user.